# When to use NoLock and ReadPast? Facing issue using both nolock and ReadPast

Tags: sql, database-deadlocks, sqlperformance, distributed-transactions, locks

Within my application, continuously transaction data is being inserted/updated by end users within begin-end transaction blocks.

Simultaneously multiple complex select statement are executed to fetch data from same tables.

Can anyone suggest how i can read data in select statements that exclude data which is not committed as transaction is still in progress and at the same time, the select statement does not lock those tables for other transactions to be inserted.

Comment: See Snapshot Isolation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You could use these:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

Select * from Table

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```